# Make android phone screen blink with different colors

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-screen, android-screen-support

I am creating an application with push notification alerts using Google C2DM service.  Can i blink the phone screen with some colors on push notification events if the phone screen is dark out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a `WakeLock` (developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) and start off an `Activity`

Comment: Ok. Can i splash my screen with some colors in this case instead of starting an activity?

Comment: I don't think you can write directly on to the screen decor. You'll have to start your own Activity.